# Display Data in Grid with Sorting and Filtering from Array in Magento Admin

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I want to display data in grid format from multidimensional array in Magento.

I have data Array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [customer_id] => 
            [Customer_Name] => Mosses41 Akizian
            [item_id] => 108
            [name] => Classic Hardshell Suitcase 29
            [qty_invoiced] => 0.0000
            [qty_ordered] => 1.0000
            [price] => 750.0000
            [created_at] => 2013-03-15 05:31:34
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [customer_id] => 30
            [Customer_Name] => Robert42 Ngia
            [item_id] => 109
            [name] => Chelsea Tee
            [qty_invoiced] => 0.0000
            [qty_ordered] => 6.0000
            [price] => 75.0000
            [created_at] => 2013-03-29 01:15:53
        )
    [2][3][.....]
)
```

Now, I want this data to displayed in admin panel as grid with sorting, pagination and grid format.

Comment: and what's the problem you having?

Comment: also what's the code you have tried?

Comment: I found this article useful: http://wizguild.com/creating-magento-admin-grid-without-database-tables/ However, I haven't yet figured out how to do sorting and search.